# Expandable TextField UI component on Blackberry/RIM OS?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm planning to port an app from Android to Blackberry (targeting BB 6.0 only). On Android, I've developed a custom expandable text field component, where the user can click on a more/less link to expand the text.

My question is whether there's an existing UI component coming with BB SDK (6.0) or any open source project that already implemented the demanded feature, or whether it also needs to be implemented from scratch.

Some details:

- The expansion is animated and the
  content which is below the text field
  moves down accordingly.
- The text is
  non-formatted (plain text) and the
  field non-editable.
- The developer
  gives the max. number of lines for
  the collapsed state
- If the text is
  longer than it fits into the
  collapsed state, "..." is added at
  the end.

[image: expandable textfield]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in component that can do this, no. The built-in components are pretty basic and haven't changed that much since the very early days. That's one criticism that developers have.

RIM has released a set of [advanced UI controls](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0) that you can use in your apps, but no text fields in that. I think you'll have to roll your own, probably wrapping a text field and a custom field within a vertical field manager.